# Optimized Lemmitization method in python

Tags: python, text-mining, lemmatization

I have written python script which have this below function. Lemmatized function taking so much time which is affecting the code efficiency. I am using spacy module for lemmatization.

```
def lemmatization(cleaned_data, allowed_postags=['NOUN', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'ADV']):
    try:
        logging.info("loading function lemmatization")
        texts = list(sent_to_words(cleaned_data))
        texts_out = []
        # Initialize spacy 'en' model, keeping only tagger component (for efficiency)
        # Run in terminal: python3 -m spacy download en
        nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner'])
        for sent in texts:
            doc = nlp(" ".join(sent))
            texts_out.append(" ".join([token.lemma_ if token.lemma_ not in ['-PRON-'] \
                                       else '' for token in doc if token.pos_ in allowed_postags]))
    except Exception as error:
        logging.info("Error occured in Lemmatization method. Error is %s", error)
    return texts_out
```

Is there any way to optimize it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `cleaned_data`?

Comment: @EPo cleaned_data is the list of text. Text is got rid of all punctuation, numbers, and unwanted text.

Comment: Any reflexions about suggested answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Variable names and variable transformations.** I do not quite understand behind what the data variables are. `cleaned_data` is text, `texts` are again a list of word and what is `sent in texts`? Things can improve if you change variable names, document args in fucntion  docstrings and add type annotations (python 3.6+). This is very typical when you work with program as a script, but unclear variables haunt both outsiode reader like myself and probably authors of code in 2-3 months from now, so better change.

**Ideas for speedup.** As for speedup there can be following cases, I think:

1. `nlp` function is slow itself
2. `nlp()` encouters lots of errors and does a lot of logging
3. something is slow in the rest of script (but these things seem rather minimal)
4. `sent_to_words()` not shown, maybe somethign happens there

**Refactoring**. For profiling the program you need to split it to fucntions to see what actiually takes a lot of time. See a refactoring below, hope it helps.

```
import logging
import spacy
from profilehooks import profile

# your actaul fucntion here
def sent_to_words(x):
    pass

# a small speedup comes from == vs in
def exclude_pron(token):
    x = token.lemma_ 
    if x == '-PRON-':
        return ''
    return x

# functional approach, could be faster than signle comprehension 
def extract_lemmas(doc, allowed_postags):
    gen = (token for token in doc if token.pos_ in allowed_postags)
    return map(exclude_pron, gen)

def make_model():
    """Initialize spacy 'en' model, keeping only tagger component for efficiency.
       Run in terminal: python3 -m spacy download en
    """
    return spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner'])

def make_texts_out(texts, nlp, allowed_postags):
    texts_out = []
    for sent in texts:
        # really important and bothering = what is 'sent'?
        doc = nlp(" ".join(sent))
        res = extract_lemmas(doc, allowed_postags)
        texts_out.append(res)
    return res

# FIXME:
# - *clean_data* is too generic variable name, better rename
# - flow of variables is unclear: cleaned_data is split to words, 
#   and then combined to text " ".join(sent) again, 
#   it is not so clear what happens 
@profile(immediate=True, entries=20)
def lemmatization(cleaned_data: list, allowed_postags=['NOUN', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'ADV']):
    logging.info("loading function lemmatization")
    texts = list(sent_to_words(cleaned_data))
    nlp = make_model()
    try:
        texts_out = list(make_texts_out(texts, nlp, allowed_postags))
    except Exception as error:
        logging.info("Error occured in lemmatization method. Error is %s", error)
    return texts_out
```